# Change background color of entire div

Tags: css

I am not at all good with CSS so need your help with below issue. I have following structure:

```
<div class="RowClass">
    <div class="CellClass1" > Test1 </div>
    <div class="CellClass2" data-value= "Summer" > </div>
    <div class="CellClass2" data-value= "Winter" > </div>
    <div class="CellClass2" data-value= "Monsoon" > </div>
</div>
```

Purpose of above structure is have a row, and different cells inside a single row. Cells with Class "CellClass2" have data-value attribute because, we want to change background color of cell(not just the text inside) according to the value in cell. For that, we have used below:

```
.CellClass2::after{
  content: attr(data-value);
}
.CellClass2[data-value="Summer"]:after {
  color: white;
  background : Yellow;
}
```

The above code works just fine. It changes the color to white and background to blue. Only problem is we want entire cell to be blue. It just changes the text background to yellow.

Please help to fix the above scenario.

EDIT: Adding CSS for both rowclass and cellclass2 :

```
.CellClass2{ 
  display:  table-cell ;
  text-align :  center ;
  border:  solid ;
   border-color :  gray ;
  text-align :  center ;
  color:black;
  height :  30px ;
  padding-top :  10px ;   
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 7px;  
  padding-left: 7px;
  border-width: thin;    
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.RowClass{
display :   table-row ;
background:  #eee ;
padding:  20px ;
margin:  20px ;
font-weight : bold ;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 200%;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use * selector..

Comment: Can you please help where to put * selector? Also will putting * impact other cells in row(which has different classname)?

Comment: Do you have margins in the divs? Margins aren't coloured by the `background` property. It might be possible to change the margins into paddings though; we would have to see all the code.

Comment: That's what you get for using `::after` pseudo-selector where it should not be used. CSS is designed to style *content*. Your `div` elements are empty, they have no content. You are trying to bend CSS in order for it to do something it isn't designed to do. You should rethink your structure, and, probably, consider using scripting and/or, perhaps, an XSLT processor.

Comment: `.CellClass2[data-value="Summer"] { background-color: yellow; }`

Comment: @MrLister, We are not using margins, edited the answer with styles included. There is margin in Rowcalss though. Would that be causing and issue?

Comment: @connexo, Thank you so much. This worked!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `:after` in the `.CellClass2[data-value="Summer"]` section

```css
.CellClass2::after{
  content: attr(data-value);
}
.CellClass2[data-value="Summer"] {
  color: white;
  background : Yellow;
}
.CellClass2{ 
  display:  table-cell ;
  text-align :  center ;
  border:  solid ;
   border-color :  gray ;
  text-align :  center ;
  color:black;
  height :  30px ;
  padding-top :  10px ;   
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 7px;  
  padding-left: 7px;
  border-width: thin;    
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.RowClass{
display :   table-row ;
background:  #eee ;
padding:  20px ;
margin:  20px ;
font-weight : bold ;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div class="RowClass">
    <div class="CellClass1" > Test1 </div>
    <div class="CellClass2" data-value= "Summer" > </div>
    <div class="CellClass2" data-value= "Winter" > </div>
    <div class="CellClass2" data-value= "Monsoon" > </div>
</div>
```